# Conditional regular expression - if a pattern exists use one regular expression and if another pattern exists use another regular expression

Tags: regex

I got strings such as these:

```
'Age at death (years) 0.0'  
'Age at death 0.0'
```

In both cases I need to capture `Age at death`.
To capture the desired string in the first example I used `.+(?= \(?.+\)?)`, and for the second I used `.+(?= \d+\.\d+)`. Adding `|` between the two in one expression didn't work as needed.

I'm looking for a way to combine the two so that they will be used conditionally for each scenario.

**More examples**

```
'Weight (pre-imaging) (Kg) 1.0'
'Body mass index (BMI) more text to be captured (Kg/m2) 0.0'
```

In these examples the first parentheses in each sentence need to be captured rather than omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^.*?(?=\s*[\d(])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bmI0N3/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*[\d(])`  - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more whitespaces and then a digit or `(` immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: This works. Thanks. Though, I just tried that string manipulation and it can get the same result. I'm not sure which one is better.

Comment: @random If you explain where you are doing this, I could help you. If you keep the environment details a secret, then sorry.

Comment: You mean what language I use? I'm using python.

Comment: @random `' '.join(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x.isalpha(), text.split()))` can also be used., See [this demo](https://ideone.com/q2f8oN).

Comment: Thanks. `' '.join(a_string.split(' (')[0].split()[:-1])` also works. I don't know which is better.

Comment: @random All three follow different logic. If you can explain what the EXACT requirements are, then you can use the "best" solution.

Comment: I think that the best solution would be the fastest. I'll try to measure their running times.

Comment: If you find the fastest solution that does not yield the results you expect on a larger sample set, what good is the speed benchmark? Actually, [our solutions differ](https://ideone.com/CLx04H) in the results.